# How to display array content when i click a article title in a row of mysql data table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im new to PHP and MySQL.

Im developing a song lyrics website something like this http://mysongbook.ca

Im using arrays to pull lyrics

```
              $lyrics = array(


                   "Move move move" => array(

                    "title" => "Move move move",
                    "artist"    => "Zayn Malik",
                    "Lyrics"    => "bla bla bla bla bla bla <br> bla bla bla bla bla bla",
                    "genres"    => "pop"

                ),       );
```

This is the data table.

```
--------------------------------
| id | title | artist | genres |
--------------------------------
```

I know how to make a table in MySQL but i dont know how to direct the columns to arrays/php pages.

Im trying to do this http://mysongbook.ca/publicsearch.php?browseArtist=a

when we click the title it should direct to lyrics php page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a php script where you connect to the database and write a query:

```
$username="your_username";$password="your_password";$database="your_database";

mysqli_connect(localhost,$username,$password);

$query="your_select_statement"
$result=mysqli_query($query);
```

Here $result is an array and you can parse it in a while statement.

Comment: hey thq.. i need another help.. how to list out the results of an artist.. something like.. row 1, row 4 and row 10 have the same artist.. so how can it be listed out.. if we click artist name in the column on mysql data table the similar results should be displayed in another page with same format of the table.